# How to construct context-free language $L$ to prove $L′=\{x|xx∈L\}$ is not context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

Can someone please explain me how to solve this?

In this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1652/the-operator-al-w-mid-ww-in-l) here was one user sketching the solution but I still don't understand how to construct a context-free language $L$ in such a way that the words in $L$ of the form $ww$ are $a^mb^mc^ma^mb^mc^m(m≥0)$. How does the grammar for L looks like? What equalities have the grammar to ensure and why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at
$$L = \{a^nb^nc^ma^mb^kc^l : n, m, k, l \geq 0\}.$$

Now take some $x \in L$ with $x = ww$, then $x = a^nb^nc^ma^mb^kc^l$ for some $n, m, k, l \geq 0$.
There's only *one* possible way to split $x$ into two equal parts $w$:

$$w = a^nb^nc^m = a^mb^kc^l.$$

Note that for distinct symbols $c_i$, $c_1^{n_1}c_2^{n_2}...c_k^{n_k} = c_1^{m_1}c_2^{m_2}...c_k^{m_k}$ implies $n_i = m_i$ for all $i$.
From this we know that

1. $n = m$,
2. $n = k$, and
3. $m = l$.

So from 1. it follows that $A(L) = \{a^nb^nc^n : n \geq 0\}$ which is [known to be not context-free](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33153/is-an-bn-cn-context-free).
To prove that $L$ is context free, note that $L$ can be generated by the following context-free grammar with start variable $S$:

$$S \to ABCD$$
$$A \to aAb | \varepsilon$$
$$B \to cBa | \varepsilon$$
$$C \to bC | \varepsilon$$
$$D \to cD | \varepsilon$$

Comment: That makes so sense, thanks!

Comment: @shinichi Glad to hear :)

Comment: Did you mean something along the lines of 1.-3. by "What equalities have the grammar to ensure"?
I wasn't entirely sure what was meant by that.

Comment: yes that's what I meant!
One clarification question: Why is it $a^m$ and not e.g. $a^s$ with $s \geq 0$?
One thing that comes to my mind is to ensure that the only combination to split $x$ in equal parts $w$ is $w=a^n b^n c^m=a^mb^kc^l$. If $L=\{a^nb^nc^m=a^sb^kc^l| n,m,s,k,l \geq 0\}$ then there would be the possiblity of the word $ww=cc$.
Is that the reason?

Comment: Yes, exactly!
A nice way to get to a solution like mine or the one by Hendrik Jan is by starting off with your example language, setting up equations like 1.-3. for it, and then to figure out what additional restrictions on $m, s, k, l$ you would need to prove $A(L) = \{a^nb^nc^n : n \geq 0\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Context-free languages are not closed under intersection. We start there.
The relevant example is here that
$\{ a^p b^p c^q \mid p,q\ge 0 \} \cap \{ a^p b^q c^q \mid p,q\ge 0 \} = K$, where $K = \{ a^m b^m c^m \mid m\ge 0 \}$ is not context-free.

The two languages each force a pair of letters to have the same number.

For your question we set $L = \{ a^p b^p c^q \mid p,q\ge 0 \} \cdot \{ a^p b^q c^q \mid p,q\ge 0 \}$. Or, written differently
$L = \{ a^p b^p c^q a^r b^s c^s \mid p,q,r,s\ge 0 \}$.
If  a string in $L$ is of the form $xx$ the two $abc$-halves must be equal. Thus of the form $x= a^m b^m c^m$.

Comment: Thanks thats a neat way to solve it! I didnt consider closure properties. 
The decision to concatenate with $\{a^pb^qc^q | p,q\geq 0\}$ is to ensure that there is no other word in the form $ww$ in $L$ then $abcabc$, right?